# Does this hard disk drive support hardware-based full disk encryption? What are some effective interrogation tactics?

Tags: windows, mac-osx, hard-drive, encryption

I am trying to determine if a particular hard disk drive supports [hardware-based full disk encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption). I know I can use the model number and check the manufacturer's website, but that is only feasible if I were doing this for a handful of computers. I have a fleet of about 1000 computers that I want to check for this.

Is there some utility or script that I can run on a remote computer that will query a hard disk drive and find out whether it supports hardware-based full disk encryption? What are some effective hard disk interrogation tactics?

I spent some time searching for a way to do this, but I ended up in a dark alley hearing whispers of [IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559309%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and got scared away.

The vast majority of computers I would like to check are running Windows (XP, Vista, and 7), but I do have several Mac OS X computers that I would like to check, too.

Comment: After reading [the blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/12/12/some-updates-to-the-faq/) I realized this may be more appropriate on Server Fault.

Comment: You might have some luck using [hdparam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm) and a batch file.

Comment: Note that the drive itself isn't the only requirement. You also need a uefi environment (or some equivalent) preboot environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `gwmi win32_diskdrive | foreach {$_.model}` to retrieve drive models.
This can easily be expanded to run across the enterprise.  More importantly than the drive is going to be whether the bios and/or controller firmware support the drive.  While you can install a hardware encrypted drive in any system, not every system will turn on the encryption.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with gathering inventory of hardware you have; probably, it's not so many hard drive models at the end. For instance, you can use smartctl from [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/) (they have a Windows version) and some simple scripting to run `smartctl -a sda > logFile` on each machine and send you the report. The first few lines of the log file will contain the drive model.

When it comes to the interrogation techniques take a look [here](http://xkcd.com/538/).

Comment: +1 for the comprehensive resource on hard disk interrogation tactics.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [OCS Inventory NG](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en) to collect information on all of your hardware, including hard drive and system/motherboard model numbers. I would then run a very simple SQL query against the OCS configuration database (which is implemented comprehensibly using MySQL) to identify the different combinations of system and HDD that you have in place.